# node delete: terminator node in a singly linked list?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list

I have an implementation of deleting the current node. The condition is that: **we only know the current node.**

The way of doing this is that:

- copy the data of next node into the current one
- then delete the next node

as the following implementation:

```
public class ListNode<T> {

  private ListNode<T> next = null;
  private T data;

  public ListNode(T data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  /*
   * Add a new node after the current node
   * Time Complexity: O(1)
   */
  public void add(T data) {
    ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(data);
    newNode.setNext(this.getNext());
    this.setNext(newNode);
  }

  /*
   * Delete the current node
   * Time Complexity: O(1)
   */
  public T delete() {
    ListNode<T> nextNode = next;
    if (nextNode == null) { /* The current node is the last node. */
      return null;
    }

    T nextData = nextNode.getData();
    this.setData(nextData);
    this.setNext(nextNode.getNext());
    return nextData;
  }

  /* getters and setters */

}
```

However, there is an exception: this will not work if the current node is the last node on the list.

I can think of a way of solving this problem:

- have a special node as `TerminatorNode`, which is always at the end of a linked list.

I would like to know: How to implement it? Or, what kind of `class` this kind of node should be?

**EDIT 1:**
Just to be clear, my question is: how I can I always delete the current node, even if it is the last node on the linked list?  I would like to have a `TerminalNode`, which is always at the end of the linked list, which only just represents the linked list end. (It is something like `\0` at the end of a string.) Then other normal node can be always deleted using the same method with time O(1).

**EDIT 2:**
This is some statement on Cracking the Coding Interview:

> You could, for example, consider marking the node as dummy.

What does that mean?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you have access to the data of the next node, this implies that you have a reference to the next node as well.  Why can't you simply check if the next node be null?

Comment: My question is: how I can I always delete the current node, even if it is the last node on the linked list?  I would like to have a `TerminalNode`, which is always at the end of the linked list, which only just represents the linked list end. Then other normal node can be always deleted using the same method with time O(1).

Comment: This is not a great idea. Why have redundant data? You already have the "null" in the "next". You just need to handle the nextNode being null better. By adding on a terminator, you solve nothing.

Comment: I can delete any ''current node'' I have access to with time O(1), even though it is the last node on the list.    This is actually an interview question I got, and the answer I was told then was to have such special ''end node'.'

Comment: There's a lot of missing information: what is the expected result of a deleting the last element in a single element list? Do you have a `List<T>` type that holds a reference to the first element? How does the usage code for this list look like? Are you holding references to `ListNode<T>` somewhere to refer to its data? If this was an interview question maybe they were more interested in your approach, your analysis of the problem...

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Please see my EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's represent the terminal node like a `LinkedNode` with `data` and `next` as `null`. Let's also assume that a terminal node is the only valid way to end a list.

```
private boolean isTerminalNode() {
    return this.getData() == null && this.getNext() == null;
}
```

If the end of the list is always a terminal node, any node can be deleted except the terminal.

```
/*
 * Delete the current node Time Complexity: O(1)
 */
public T delete() {
    if (this.isTerminalNode()) {
        // Cannot delete the terminal node.
        // Either throw an IllegalArgumentException or return silently
        return null;
    }

    ListNode<T> nextNode = this.getNext();
    this.setData(nextNode.getData());
    this.setNext(nextNode.getNext());
    return this.getData();
}
```

However, now we might encounter a similar problem when adding after a node.

```
/*
 * Add a new node after the current node Time Complexity: O(1)
 */
public void add(T data) {
    if (this.isTerminalNode()) {
        // Cannot add a node after the terminal node.
        // Either throw an IllegalArgumentException, return silently, or add
        // the data at the current position and create a new terminal node.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot add a node after the terminal node");
    }

    ListNode<T> newNode = new ListNode<T>(data);
    newNode.setNext(this.getNext());
    this.setNext(newNode);
}
```